# Request for a button to copy share link to clipboard

Tags: feature-request, share

When we click "share" , there is a popup:

[image]

In the popup, I suggest we have a <kbd>Copy</kbd> button beside the textbox (and near to "share" so as to minimize mouse movement) to make it easier to copy links to the clipboard. After all, that's what the user is most likely to do next after clicking "share".

It might look like Bitly's ["Copy" button](https://bitly.com/shorten/):

[image]

or Github's ["Copy the full SHA" button](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/pull/168/commits):

[image]

Comment: Last time I checked, this required a Flash plugin to work. And if I'm not mistaken, Stack Exchange would be very reluctant to add such a thing.

Comment: It's already pre-selected, so the quickest way to copy it would be to press `Ctrl+C`.

Comment: @nhinkle No the quickest way to copy it would be to click a button. Ok, that depends on whether your left hand is faster or your right hand. But not everyone has two hands (or use two hands on the computer) you know.

Comment: @slhck Hmm I think a Java plugin would work as well. Could make it such that the button is only shown if the plugin is available and working... bitly seems to have no usability issues with it.

Comment: Yeah, except that this is the number one use case for `bit.ly`. I'm not too sure if they'd like that for Stack Exchange, is what I'm saying :)

Comment: @slhck True.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: @DanielBeck: The explicit user action would be to click the "copy link" button.

Comment: @DanielBeck What do you mean by explicit user action. If a user doesn't want to copy, then simply don't click the "copy link" button..

Comment: Right,   misread that. Sorry about that. Please edit so I can undo my vote.

Comment: @DanielBeck, ok =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just FYI, if you're looking for a one-hand only solution, try this:

[image]

The **link** itself is also a valid link to the same address.

Comment: Cool =) That's a good work around. But my point is, it is not immediately obvious (usability).

Comment: There should be a *Copy* entry in the context menu to selected text as well.

Comment: @DanielBeck, Yea, though it takes much much longer to do that. *click* + *Click* takes about 1 second. Compare that with *Click* + *movemouse* + *right click* + *movemouse* + *click*.

Comment: @Pacerier The text is already selected in the popup. (Also, doesn't Windows allow triple-clicking to select everything?)

Comment: @DanielBeck, Windows has triple-clicking too, and it's true that the text is already selected in the popup. However, *"Click + movemouse + right click + movemouse + click"* is still required. 1) click on "share" 2) move the mouse from "share" to the preselected link 3) right-click the selected link  4) move mouse from selected link to "copy" in the context menu 5) click to copy.

Comment: @Pacerier You're right of course. Thanks for the clarification.